# help installing EcoTank printer for 16.04

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I have a "bad" habit of not buying a printer until I know that it can work with Ubuntu, and not just with Windows.  I also look at the cost of 3rd party ink.  ***What I need is a way to get the new line of EcoTank printers from Epson to work with 16.04.*** The base model is "Expression ET‑2500" Since this tech is more cost effective than my current color printers, I need to be able to install it on my Ubuntu systems. I rarely run Windows anymore and it would be too much "effort" to switch to Windows to print the work.

So is there any way to do this?  Before I fork over the $300+ cash for the printer?

Comment: Precisely my father bought a Epson Et-2500, and I installed ubuntu on that old PC. Although it does not appear in : http://www.openprinting.org/printers ... I just found the correct driver provided by Epson :
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX So it is likely to found there the package for you system.

Answer (score 1):

I bought one of those printers recently, and I found this command allows me to use the printer with ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

However, I am currently looking for a Epson package I can run to allow me a wider range of printer options.

Works fine overall.